# Como funciona os métodos "restore" e "save"?

Tags: canvas

Eu estava tentando entender o funcionanmento dos métodos `save` e `restore` do `canvas` e olhei na página da [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore).

Mesmo assim ainda fiquei sem entender qual é a diferença entre usá-los ou não.

De acordo com a documentação, o `save` "salva um estado padrão" e o `restore` "restaura esse estado posteriormente".

Porém ainda não consegui entender o que o uso dos mesmos fez nesse exemplo dado lá na documentação:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.save(); // save the default state

ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);

ctx.restore(); // restore to the default state
ctx.fillRect(150, 75, 100, 100);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Qual é a finalidade do método `restore` e `save`?

Como funciona esse tal estado?

Comment: Voltou pro estado anterior, "caneta preta".

Comment: @Bacco nooooooooooooooooooooooooooosa, nem me toquei, cara! kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente o `.save` guarda o estado atual do contexto:

- A matriz de transformação atual;
- a Região de recorte;
- a lista de tracejado;
- e os valores destes atributos todos:

  ```
  strokeStyle, fillStyle, globalAlpha, lineWidth, lineCap, lineJoin, miterLimit,
  lineDashOffset, shadowOffsetX, shadowOffsetY, shadowBlur, shadowColor,        
  globalCompositeOperation, font, textAlign, textBaseline, direction,
  imageSmoothingEnabled
  ```

Documentação:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save

O `.restore` retorna ao estado anterior. Muito útil quando você vai desenhar só um pequeno detalhe de maneira diferente do resto. Veja:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// começamos com preenchimento verde
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 100);

ctx.save(); // salvamos o estado

// mudamos o preenchimento pra azul
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fillRect(50, 10, 30, 100);

ctx.restore(); // restauramos ao estado salvo

ctx.fillRect(90, 10, 30, 100);
// Notou que voltou ao verde?
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```